# Filter Array from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to filter the objects from array:

```
let x = [{a: 100, categories: [22, 23 ] 

}, {a: 101, categories: [20, 21 ] }];
let y = [22]; //can be multiple

let result = x.filter(i => y.includes(i.categories)  );
console.log(result);
// result = []
```

Expected Output:

```
[{a: 100, categories: [22, 23 ]}]
```

but I get empty array.

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you clarify a little better what is your question?

Comment: ah sorry.. i have already edited my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if some of the items are in the `categories` array.

```js
let x = [{a: 100, categories: [22, 23 ] }, {a: 101, categories: [20, 21 ] }];
let y = [22]; //can be multiple

let result = x.filter(i => y.some(a => i.categories.includes(a)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether the entire array `i.categories` is in `y`, use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any element of `i.categories` is in `y`:

```js
let x = [{a: 100, categories: [22, 23 ] }, {a: 101, categories: [20, 21 ] }];
let y = [22]; //can be multiple

let result = x.filter(i => y.some(x => i.categories.includes(x)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x`, `.categories`, or `y` is significantly large, you can achieve a significant speed improvement by first converting `y` to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). `Set.prototype.has` provides much faster lookup times, `O(1)`, compared to `Array.prototype.includes`, `O(n)` -

```js
const x =
  [ { a: 100, categories: [ 22, 23 ] }
  , { a: 101, categories: [ 20, 21 ] }
  , { a: 102 }
  ]
  
const y =
  [ 22 ] //can be multiple

const ySet =
  new Set(y) // has O(1) lookup

let result =
  x.filter(({ categories = [] }) =>
    categories.some(c => ySet.has(c)) // <-- use set lookup
  )
  
console.log(result)
// [ { a: 100, categories: [ 22, 23 ] } ]
```